# Java EE server for raspberry pi (Spring-MVC)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, raspberry-pi

I'm searching a server for Raspberry Pi that supports Java EE Spring Framework.

Does anybody have an experience with some RPi servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install Tomcat on Rasberry Pi, instructions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/how-to-get-tomcat-running-on-raspberry-pi-with-archlinux)...

You can then apply a SpringMVC application in a war without having to do anything specific to the Tomcat server.  The Spring framework support will just be in jars wrapped up in the war.

Comment: How does this work out for light loads (e.g. protyping)?